# PLSQL - Find two values are equal when they are NULL

Tags: oracle, plsql, null

I'm using a IF condition to check whether 2 values are equal or not. In one scenario all the values that I use are NULL, but it does not recognize as they are equal.

```
IF training_event_rec_.training_fee = course_rec_.course_fee AND training_event_rec_.training_fee_unit = course_rec_.course_fee_unit AND training_event_rec_.currency = course_rec_.currency AND training_evaluation_temp_ = course_evaluation_temp_ THEN
    RETURN FALSE;
ELSE
     RETURN TRUE;
END IF;
```

In here all the variables that is compared are NULL but it always hit the ELSE part.
How Can I compare values in this kind of situations.

Comment: It is an axiom of SQL that `null != null`. That's why the test always takes the ELSE branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use IS NULL:

```
IF     (training_event_rec_.training_fee = course_rec_.course_fee OR
       (training_event_rec_.training_fee IS NULL AND course_rec_.course_fee IS NULL))
   AND (training_event_rec_.training_fee_unit = course_rec_.course_fee_unit OR
        (training_event_rec_.training_fee_unit IS NULL AND course_rec_.course_fee_unit IS NULL))
   AND (training_event_rec_.currency = course_rec_.currency OR
        (training_event_rec_.currency IS NULL AND course_rec_.currency IS NULL))
   AND (training_evaluation_temp_ = course_evaluation_temp_ OR
        (training_evaluation_temp_ IS NULL AND course_evaluation_temp_ IS NULL))
THEN
    RETURN FALSE;
ELSE
     RETURN TRUE;
END IF;
```

NOTE:

- You can also compare Nulls like NVL(COLUMN_A,'X') = NVL(COLUMN_B,'X') only if you are sure that COLUMN_A & COLUMN_B will not contain value 'X'. So that is not recommended approach.

Comment: Explicitly testing for nulls is the safer option, unless the business rules give us a default value we can substitute for NULL.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Initially I thought checking for null again might not efficient and as you mentioned using NVL is not safe for my business logic.

Comment: There can be cases where you can specify a default value that is impossible to match with existing values, though as APC says it will depend on your business rules and data model. For example, if `course_fee` is `number(6,2)` then it can never match `0.001`, `1e9` or `binary_double_nan`, and if `currency` is `varchar2(3)` then it can never match `'####'`. (I'd be tempted to use `chr(0)` but I suppose it's a hack.)

Answer (score 3):

I presume there might be different combinations of non-null and null values. One option is to check them all, or - maybe simpler - use `NVL`, such as:

```
IF     nvl(training_event_rec_.training_fee, 0)      = nvl(course_rec_.course_fee, 0)
   AND nvl(training_event_rec_.training_fee_unit, 0) = nvl(course_rec_.course_fee_unit, 0)
   AND nvl(training_event_rec_.currency, 0)          = nvl(course_rec_.currency, 0)
   AND nvl(training_evaluation_temp_, 0)             = nvl(course_evaluation_temp_, 0)
THEN
   RETURN FALSE;
ELSE
   RETURN TRUE;
END IF;
```

Depending on datatypes, you might need to use something else, not `0`. For example, currency might be USD or EUR or something like that, so you'd use

```
nvl(training_event_rec_.currency, 'x')
```

Comment: The danger with using NVL() is that might generate false matches. If `course_rec_.course_fee` = 0 and `training_event_rec_.training_fee` is null then they are not the same. Maybe the business rules say we can treat them as being the same but that is not stated. So I think explicitly testing for IS NULL is the safer solution.